# Why Don't we Use General Exception Class (Exception) for Catching All Types Of Exceptions

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio

Why do we use the more specific exceptions like `IndexOutOfRangeException`
and `DivideByZero` exceptions when we can catch them in a `catch` block like this:

```
try
{
    //Some Work
}
catch(Exception E){}
```

Comment: Only catch exceptions you can do something about. Don't leave your app in an invalid state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only ever write specific code to handle exceptions that you reasonably expect to be thrown. If you understand that specific code could throw a specific type of exception then you can determine exactly what to do in that situation.  If you catch absolutely any type of exception then you will have no idea what the cause was and thus you can't know what should be done about it.